# How does XGBoost deal with overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting, boosting

The question as stated is very general, but I'm asking it because I find weird that I got the following scores using 100 or more trees with XGBoost:

- AUC on training set 1 (perfect classifier).
- AUC on test set 0,77.

The first AUC on training set seems to indicate overfitting, of course. But the issue is that the second score is decent, and if I reduce the number of trees, I can optimize the AUC on test around 20 trees, getting a value of 0,79 AUC. It's not a huge improvement. IN this case the AUC on training set will not be perfect, but 0,9 approx.
So the question is: how can it be that with a model that has learned perfectly the training set you can generalize so well? Isn't weird? I think that with other models the typical situation with overfitting is that the error on test set tends to increase wildly.

Comment: It's not that weird. Adjusting the learning rate and early stopping has a large effect on overfitting. So does $L^2$ regularization. Some relevant threads: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bxgboost%5D+regularization

Comment: Thanks! I will look in other questions. But I mean that, assuming there is always noise and randomness (at least, there is in the real problem I'm trying to solve), I would have supposed that a perfect classifier on the trainig set will generalze much, much worse that a not-so-good classifier. And this was not the case...

Comment: To the extent that the perfect score on the training data is signal, not noise, the model is learning something. The classic depiction of a squiggly boundary between two classes being an example of overfitting is a nice teaching tool, but slightly misleading. It's possible that the squiggly line is really the truth. Most of the task of building a good ML model is working out schemes to check if the squiggle is signal or noise, or finding a squiggle that generalizes well anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It could be, I'm not an expert at all, but if this were the truth in the model that I am building, I would be really surprised!!

Comment: And that's what your test AUC is telling you -- the model has learned some information from the training data, but the model is imperfect.